# How can I calculate a field using above result with current in an Extjs grid?

Tags: extjs

I want the result will like as below table.

*Before Balance stock =2000*

Row 1 2000-100=1900

Row 2 1900-150=1750

TABLE 1

```
|-----Date------|----Product----|-----sales-----|----Balance------|
|--2013-08-01---|-------P1------|------100------|------1900-------|
|--2013-08-03---|-------p1------|------150------|------1750-------|
```

I have tried:

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
return record.get('stock')-record.get('sales');
},
```

```
|-----Date------|----Product----|-----sales-----|----Balance------|
|--2013-08-01---|-------P1------|------100------|------1900-------|
|--2013-08-03---|-------p1------|------150------|------1850-------|
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I calculate the balance like as above table 1?

Comment: What currently happens with the code you have?  And can you post your Model code?

Comment: Balance will not like as table 1

Comment: Just to clear out the problem a bit, the **1900** from "Row 2 **1900**-150=1750" comes from the result on Row 1??